# Infinite Looping between IdP and SP servers in SAML Spring Application

Tags: spring, saml, opensaml, idp

We have encountered an issue where the application is going into an infinite looping state between the IdP server and the SP server, which are both hosted by different servers. From the logs, we could observe that the authentication was successful and we were able to get the assertion data as well. But at the browser level, we could see that the application was redirecting to IdP server. There were no errors logged in either browser console or in application/tomcat console. Could anyone please help me find a solution to stop this behavior.

Our Environment - Spring Framework application with open saml2 hosted on tomcat server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it could be tough to point out your problem quickly. Nevertheless, I wanted to write my comments maybe you can find a way worth to look.

IdP, SP, and your application are crucial players in such integration. The proper configuration between IdP and SP is the most important step. The user logins on the identity provider then redirect to SP with SAML assertion with desired attributes inside of a contract which IdP and SP have been agreed on. My suggestion would be, "it might be worthy of having a look at configuration once again."

Sorry, I don't have a concrete solution at this point to help you in resolving your problem. It might be hard for you also to give detailed information about integration between ends. But if you can provide a piece of more details like the name of the products (IdP, SP, SAML configuration details, i.e., which attributes have been mapped) that you are using, I can try to find sth.

Comment: There is a load balancer configured between the SP and IdP. On checking the load balancer settings, we found that JSESSIONID value, usually set by the SP, was being over-ridden by the LB. Thanks for answering my query!!